# "What are you thinking" vs "What are you thinking about"

Tags: verbs

Someone's very quiet and sitting alone. I go over and ask them,

> You look very quiet. What are you thinking?

Is this correct? Or should I say instead,

> What are you thinking about?

Or are both correct and can be used interchangeably?

Comment: Just popping in to add a question to the post: It seems to me "what are you thinking?" sort of implies that the speaker thinks the one he/she is talking is not thinking straight. But I am not sure whether that is true for native speakers.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want to know, which one is better in this context. And if there's a difference between the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was my first impression:

> Q: What are you thinking about?

This asks for the particular matter that’s being thought. You don’t really have an idea about the person’s thoughts.

> A1: Oh, nothing.
>   A2: A friend.
>   A3: How we used to play under the tree by the river when we were kids, remember?

It slightly differs from

> Q: What are you thinking?

This ask for the details about the matter that’s being thought. In other words, you know (or think you know) that the person is thinking about X, and you want to know the details. For example, you know (or think) the person is devising a plan, and you want the specifics:

> A1: We pitch him away: cutter, cutter, slider.
>   A2: I’m calling Joe in the morning to have him move the money.
>   A3: That I should start looking for a new job.

So in your scenario, if I haven’t talked to the person, and I was curious about their thoughts, I’d ask, “What are you thinking about?”

If I felt like they were thinking intently about something (they get quiet when they’re planning something, for example), I could ask, “What are you thinking?”

Anyway, this was just my first impression. I imagine some might disagree, or find additional usages. Let’s see!

Comment: A beautiful explanation. It clears up everything, thanks a lot. The way you explained "what are you thinking?", I think it's similar to the situation when we overestimate ourselves, but end up faltering, and we say in frustration, "What was I thinking?" Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. We/you know what it’s _about_ (the exam, the assignment, the money, etc). You want to know the details, the thought process, the logic, etc (although, in your case, it’s often said rhetorically).